# Trying to display some data from mysql DB = blank page

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "toor");
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

$select_db = mysql_select_db('test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: main.php");
}
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

/*if (isset($_GET['id']){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $query = "SELECT title FROM news WHERE id=$id";
    $title = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $query = "SELECT body FROM news WHERE id=$id";
    $body = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "$title\n\n\n";
    echo "$body\n\n";
}*/
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>
Login OK
</body>
</html>
```

I need to display the content of the fields title and body, however I'm getting a blank page (not even the link to logout.php is displayed). There is no error reported by `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`.

If I comment the if block, both the link to logout.php and the message "Login OK" are displayed.

What might be failing?

In the login.php I call news.php with:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: news.php?id=1");
}
```

**edit**

I'm noticing the call to news.php?id=1 returns an error 500.

Comment: `echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";` should be inside `<html><body>`, you don't need to call a php file with `header` just use `include()`

Comment: he uses header to redirect. if the user is not logged. I don-t think he needs to include the file.

Comment: Do not use mysql functions... you need to used mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @user3806613 the point is to make this application vulnerable.

Comment: ok... strange but each to their own.

Comment: maybe is a demo, anyway i would go to check the logs, the error is clearly written there and will save you headaches. /var/log/httpd/error_log generally on linux.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi just was coming to said I've got it fixed xD Indeed, checking the error_log I noticed that there was a ')' missing in the `if (isset($_GET['id']){`. Edit your answer, saying to check apache logs as well, so I can accept it.

Comment: I looked at that code searching for a missing parenthesis or a ';' at least 5 minutes but. because it had to be something like that. but i could not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it in the wrong way

```
$query = "SELECT title, body FROM news WHERE id=$id";
$results = mysql_query($query);
while ($news = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  echo $news["title"];
  echo $news["body"];
}
```

the instruction mysql_query will give you a result set.
Then from results sets you have to fetch the single rows
with mysql_fetch_assoc ( or fetch_row or fetch_array, see the manual for the differencies )
Then with single result pulled you display data.

In your code i cannot see any db connection logic, there is no connection parameter passed to mysql_query function.

Error 500 means php is doing some bad error and fails to execute, anyway i would go to check the logs, the error is clearly written there and will save you headaches. /var/log/httpd/error_log generally on linux.

Comment: still blank page and http code 500. The application can access the db without problem as sign in is been made without any problem.

Comment: mmm that's true, I had not added connection code in this script, just in the sign in script. Just added it, same as in my login.php, still error 500.

Comment: Sign in is made in the login page. once you redirect you have to connect to db again. How did you setup the db connection in login.php page? ok sorry did not notice second comment.